# Django templates don't show my all parameters

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have problem. I want create relationship in model Django. I would like every user to have a different product price. The product must be assigned to the user. It must is to display only after logging in. Unfortunately, the template does not show all parameters.

offers/models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  category = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  weight = models.FloatField()
  description = models.TextField(blank=True)
  photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/')
  is_published  = models.BooleanField(default=True)
  list_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.title

class UserProduct(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  title = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
  price = models.FloatField()
  is_published  = models.BooleanField(default=True)
  list_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)

  def __str__(self):
    return str(self.user.username) if self.user.username else ''
```

Products are to be displayed for logged in users.

offers/views.py

```
def index(request):
  context = {
      'products': Product.objects.order_by('category').filter(is_published=True)
  }
  return render(request, 'offers/products.html', context)


def userproduct(request):
   context = {
      'userproduct': UserProduct.objects.filter(user_id=request.user.id),
      'userproduct1': Product.objects.all()
  }
   return render(request, 'offers/userproducts.html', context)
```

My template show only title, and price.

offers/userproducts.html

```
<!-- Offers -->
        <section class="text-center mb-4 py-4">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                {% if userproduct %}
                {% for product in userproduct %}

            <!--Grid column-->
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="view overlay">
                  <img src="{{ product.photo.url }}" class="card-img-top" alt="">
                  <a href="{% url 'product' product.id %}">
                    <div class="mask rgba-white-slight"></div>
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body text-center">
                    <h6 class="grey-text">{{ product.category }}</h6>
                  <h5>
                    <strong>
                      <a href="{% url 'product' product.id %}" class="dark-grey-text">{{ product.title }}</a>
                    </strong>
                  </h5>
                  <h4 class="font-weight-bold colores">
                    <strong>{{ product.price }}</strong>
                  </h4>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!--Grid column-->

            {% endfor %}
            {% else %}
              <div class="col-sm-12 sm-12">
                <p>No Products Available XD</p>
              </div>
            {% endif %}
            {% endif %}

          </div>
        </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: But `product` is a UserProduct. It doesn't have `photo` or `category` fields.

Comment: So, I would like UserProduct to choose user, product, and I could set the price and download these fields to userproducts.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `userproduct` queryset that you are iterating over belongs to `UserProduct` model which doesn't have the fields you're looking for.

This is how it should be:

```
<!-- Offers -->
    <section class="text-center mb-4 py-4">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            {% if userproduct %}
            {% for product in userproduct %}

        <!--Grid column-->
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="view overlay">
              <img src="{{ product.title.photo.url }}" class="card-img-top" alt="">
              <a href="{% url 'product' product.title.id %}">
                <div class="mask rgba-white-slight"></div>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body text-center">
                <h6 class="grey-text">{{ product.title.category }}</h6>
              <h5>
                <strong>
                  <a href="{% url 'product' product.title.id %}" class="dark-grey-text">{{ product.title.title }}</a>
                </strong>
              </h5>
              <h4 class="font-weight-bold colores">
                <strong>{{ product.price }}</strong>
              </h4>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--Grid column-->

        {% endfor %}
        {% else %}
          <div class="col-sm-12 sm-12">
            <p>No Products Available XD</p>
          </div>
        {% endif %}
        {% endif %}

      </div>
    </div>
    </section>
```

If you need a field from `Product` model, you should get the `Product` instance which is `title`. So:

- Price: `product.price`
- Title: `product.title.title` (`product.title` also works because of your `__str__` function.)
- Category: `product.title.category`
- Photo: `product.title.photo`
- And so on ...

Comment: Worth pointing out that `title` is a very silly name for the FK to Product.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Yes, `product` would be a much better name. Also, `on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING` is not a good idea in this case.

Comment: You are the best. Thank you!, so you can write for me correct field? And why on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING is not a good idea in this case?

Comment: @yellowhand No problem. And what do you mean by "write for me correct field"?

Comment: `models.DO_NOTHING` is not a good idea because you are very depended on your `Product` model. So there is no point for having the instance when you deleted the main product. `models.CASCADE` is a better choice.

Comment: How should i do with FK Product, but title is a very silly name fore the FK.

Comment: @yellowhand If you changed `title` to `product` you also need to change the fields in your template. Like this: `product.product.category`

Comment: Now I understand everything. Thank you.